# Replacing the 0's in a column with mode corresponding to another column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

The above data frame have 9 product of 3 different classes. The attributes of these products are quality and taste.

Attributes in some of the products reads 0 which is wrong and it have to be replaced by the mode of its class. Like the below figure

[image]

I have grouped it based on its mode
data.groupby(['class'])['quality','taste'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])

But kindly help me to replace the 0s with the mode corresponding to its class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` with `replace`:

```
data[['quality','taste']] = data.groupby(['class'])['quality','taste'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(0, x.value_counts().index[0]))
```

Or use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.value_counts().index[0]
    m = x == 0
    x[m] = a
    return x

data[['quality','taste']] = data.groupby(['class'])['quality','taste'].transform(f)
```